# Insert record with all values as AutoIncrement or Default

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with 2 columns.

1. key - Primary key, Auto Increment
2. timestamp - DateTime, Default -> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I am trying to insert a value into this table with the help of SqliteOpenHelper object. But it throws an exception:

```
public void logTime() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_LOG_TIME, null, new ContentValues());
}
```

Exception:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "null": syntax error
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting 
      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO log_time(null) VALUES (NULL)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
      at com.livinglifetechway.mytime.db.DatabaseHelper.logScreenUnlock(DatabaseHelper.java:62)
      at com.livinglifetechway.mytime.ScreenUnlockBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ScreenUnlockBroadcastReceiver.java:25)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:153)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Database onCreate call:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // Create Statements
    String CREATE_TABLE_LOG_TIME = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOG_TIME + " " +
            "(" +
            KEY_LOG_TIME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_LOG_TIME_TIME + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
            ")";

    // Execute statements
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOG_TIME);

}
```

All values are default/auto_increment values.

How can I insert a record in this table?

Comment: what are the things you are doing before  db.insert(TABLE_LOG_TIME, null, new ContentValues()); can u show ?

Comment: Your database implementation code?

Comment: @Rahul Those 2 lines are inside simple plain method.

Comment: can i see your table structure ?

Comment: @Rahul I have edited question with more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a row with default values, specify at least one column with null value:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.putNull(KEY_LOG_TIME_TIME);
db.insert(TABLE_LOG_TIME, null, cv);
```

Comment: I didn't new about `putNull`

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
db.insert(TABLE_LOG_TIME, null, new ContentValues());
```

with

```
db.insert(TABLE_LOG_TIME, null, null);
```